# Page numbers show up in table of contents, but NOT on pages

Tags: latex, tex

Page numbers show correctly up in the table of contents, but not on the pages. How can I make LaTex display them on the pages in the document?

I have tried changing the documentclass from report to article and adding the hyperref package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-5em}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}


\newpage
\doublespacing
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

Comment: please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem instead of a code fragment

Answer (score 0):

I do get page numbers in this minimal example, both for documentclass article as report:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
% \documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{one}
\newpage
\section{two}
\newpage
\section{three}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

You may not get a page number because you explicitly say so using `\thispagestyle{empty}`. Report may also define the first page (of a chapter) as a page without regular head and foot, and hence also without number.

Hyperref has nothing to do with (printed) page numbers.

Comment: when I remove ```\thispagestyle{empty}``` , then the page number shows up at the bottom of the table of contents page, but still not in the rest of the document

Comment: @serpentina Hard to say. Please [edit] your question and include a [mcve]. Or try my code above, and if it works, adapt yours to match.

Comment: It worked, when deleting more ```\thispagestyle{empty}``` and inserting ```\pagenumbering{gobble}``` instead. Thanks!